# List cron jobs in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron

I am looking for a way to list all magento 2 cron jobs. Is it available somewhere easy to review?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I decided to get cron jobs list by performing following simple query on a database:

```
select job_code from cron_schedule GROUP BY job_code;
```

but it's neither handy nor detailed. Maybe somebody has a better idea...

Answer (score 16):

You can run `n98-magerun2` command line utility to list all cronjobs.

If you run the following command in your magento installation, it will display all the cronjobs available in your magento.

`n98-magerun2 sys:cron:list`

For more detailed tutorial, please visit [my medium article](https://medium.com/@inanbunyamin90/how-to-list-all-cron-jobs-in-magento-2-de72379ec711).

Comment: This is what I use, very useful tool!

Comment: Third party tool but still, I agree that it's very useful. Perfect for development

Comment: should be n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:list for now.

Comment: This is not working for me.. I am not sure whether this is available at present or not. I have downloaded this plugin but "n98-magerun2 sys:cron:list" command says "bash: n98-magerun2: command not found".

Answer (score 1):

@Luke I needed to review CRON jobs too and I couldn't find any simple solution.

I went the lazy way and used grep to find all `<job>` entries and put them into one file for easier review:

```
grep -r -A 2 "<job" . > cron.txt
```

It's not a great solution, but it may help at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can check following URLs for cron job in Magento 2.

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html
- http://inchoo.net/magento-2/running-cron-jobs-in-magento-2/

Get cron list from database using following SQL query:

> select job_code from cron_schedule GROUP BY job_code;

Comment: The question is about listing active cron jobs, not running them or creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Wojtek Naruniec's answer (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198682/104439), but tweaked a bit to skip irrelevant directories, and avoid the redirected file from reading itself;

```
grep -r -A 2 "<job" app/code/ vendor/ > var/system_cronjobs.txt
```

Run from the M2 root directory and it will get any system cron jobs that run during `cron:run` executions. Plus dump to `var/` so it works on MCloud as well.