# What are the different Magento 2 cron jobs doing?

Tags: magento2, cron

Magento 2 specifies three cron jobs to be run:

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

What are each of these three cron jobs doing, specifically?

Comment: What you pasted there are not three cron jobs. But three ways to run your cron. 
Possible duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197540/list-cron-jobs-in-magento-2

Comment: No, they are three system cron jobs. You might be confusing system cron jobs with Magento cron jobs. System cron jobs are specified in OS crontab, while Magento cron jobs are specified in Magento's own cron system.

Comment: I would like to know this too... it seems like `cron:run`, `cron.php`, and `setup:cron:run` are all semantically similar... are there like three types of cron jobs in Magento 2 I don't know about that run in different cases? Why can't `cron:run` just run all the cron jobs?

Comment: This has been answered before here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/204602

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reasons to setup cronjob for setup:cron:run and update/cron.php on a deployed production system?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134443/reasons-to-setup-cronjob-for-setupcronrun-and-update-cron-php-on-a-deployed-pr)